# Testing Django Models with FileField

Tags: django, unit-testing

I'm trying to make the transition to testing with Django.  This is the particular model in question for testing:

```
class Media(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='upload',)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='upload', blank=True,)

    # ...
```

PART 1:  How do I deal with these FileFields? (Particularly in the sense that I need to generate fake entries to test bits of code)

PART 2:  Below is the testing code I've begun to write.  Am I doing this correctly or should I be using a form of "mocking"?

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from mediamanager.models import Media

class MediaManagerTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.fake_user = User.objects.create(username='fakeuser', is_staff=false)   
        self.fake_staff = User.objects.create(username='fakestaff', is_staff=true)    
        self.fake_admin = User.objects.create(username='fakeadmin', is_superuser=true)

        self.fake_media_image = Media.objects.create()  # Hmmm...
        self.fake_media_video = Media.objects.create()  # How do i do this...

    def testMediaCanEdit(self):
        perm = self.fake_media_image.can_edit(self.fake_user)
        self.assertEquals(perm, false)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a partial answer to my question, and to help anyone else who found this question from a search.

Django includes a facility it refers to as ['fixtures'](http://www.google.com/search?q=django+fixtures&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) to handle the primary loading of data during testing.  Creating a fixture is a 2 step process:

1. Add some fake data to the app's model using the admin tool
2. Run the following:  manage.py dumpdata [appname] --indent=2 > filename.json

The fixture file *.json remains in your Django project root folder.

In your tests.py file, you can load the fixture on the Django TestCase class as so:

```
class YourTestCase(TestCase):    
    fixtures = ['filename.json','whatever.json',]
```

Once the fixture is loaded, you can use the data as you would normally use the ORM.  Here's my working test case from the above code if you'd like an example.

```
from django.test import TestCase

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from mediamanager.models import Media

class MediaManagerTestCase(TestCase):

    fixtures = ['auth_data.json','mediamanager_data.json',]

    def setUp(self):
        self.fakeuser = User.objects.get(username='fakeuser')
        self.fakestaff = User.objects.get(username='fakestaff')
        self.fakeadmin = User.objects.get(username='fakeadmin')

    def test_media_can_edit(self):
        um = Media.objects.get(pk=1)    # Media owned by fakeuser
        sm = Media.objects.get(pk=2)    # Media owned by fakstaff

        self.assertEquals(um.can_edit(self.fakeuser), True)
        self.assertEquals(sm.can_edit(self.fakeuser), False)

        self.assertEquals(um.can_edit(self.fakestaff), True)
        self.assertEquals(sm.can_edit(self.fakestaff), True)

        self.assertEquals(um.can_edit(self.fakeadmin), True)
        self.assertEquals(sm.can_edit(self.fakeadmin), True)
```

Answer (score 20):

Hi i just had the same problem, after some googling i ended up with:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.files import File as DjangoFile
from home.models import Tab, File

class FileModelTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.tab = Tab.objects.create(
                title="Title",
                html="<p>test</p>",
                published=True
            )
        self.file = File.objects.create(
                tab=self.tab,
                file=DjangoFile(open("home/tests/models.py"), "test_file.css")
            )

    def tearDown(self):
        self.file.delete()
        self.tab.delete()
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I couldn't make your tearDown example work. What did work for me was os.remove(self.tab.file.path)

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your files after fixtures creation:

```
def setUp(self):
    files = UpFile.objects.all()
    for file in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, file.upfile.name)
        open(filepath, 'w').close()
```